# Why multiple-cursors NOT mark all text between all square brackets?

Tags: multiple-cursors

emacs 26.1

I want to downcase all text between **all** square brackets. So I try to use `multiple-cursors` for this:

here text:

```
CREATE TABLE [CIndicators] (
[ID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
[CODE] VARCHAR(1)  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
[DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,
[DESCRIPTION_RO] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,
[DESCRIPTION_RU] VARCHAR(255) NULL
);
```

Mark first open square bracket and use `mc/mark-all-like-this`

here result:

[image]

Nice.
Now move cursor one char forward:

[image]

Nice. And now use `mark-sexp` (`C-=`) to mark all text inside square brackets.

[image]

But as you can see it mark only text in first square brackets (**CIndicators**). But why `multiple-cursors` not mark all another text in another square brackets, like **CODE**, **DESCRIPTION** and so on?

Comment: When I do it (C-M-@), it asks me if I want to do it for all cursors. I say "Yes" and it does it.

Using: 20190317.1211

Comment: In this case the region is active so `mark-sexp` won't work. You should use `forward-sexp` instead (or `sp-forward-sexp` if you use smartparens).

Comment: @jagrg "forward-sexp" in normal mode it just forward to next one word. But in multiple-cursors it select next one word. Nice. But I not find help about this behavior of "forward-sexp". Where you find this second behavior?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? Which second behaviour?

Comment: @jagrg forward-sexp in multi-cursors mode select/mark next word.

Comment: This also help - C-M-u C-M-SPC (i.e., while holding the Control and Meta keys, press u and Space in sequence). Get from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5194568/6813231

Comment: Hm. I'm still not sure what the issue is. Does `forward-sexp` not solve your problem?

Comment: @jagrg forward-sexp can't solve my problem (by one press)when I need to mark all text (e.g. 3 words) between square brackets. But C-M-u C-M-SPC can help for this.

Comment: In that case you're right, forward-sexp won't work, unless the point is *before* the opening bracket, in which case you need an extra step (start with the point here `|[`): 1. `C-SPC` to set the mark, 2. `C-f` 3. `M-x mc/mark-all-like-this` 4. `C-b` 5. `C-M-f` (`forward-sexp`). BTW with smartparens you can do this in fewer steps using `sp-up-sexp` which moves forward out of one level of parentheses.